# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in developer command prompt for VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, tls1.2

I want to generate proxy class and then I opened developer command prompt for VS 2017.
After that I followed below steps to do it.
[image]

But I received "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel" error. How can I set TLS 1.2 in developer command prompt for VS 2017?.
How can I get rid of above issue when creating proxy class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you open that URL at all in a browser? If not, you can't use any tools with it. Windows 10 (the only supported Windows version) used TLS1.2 by default, there's nothing to set. Are you using an unsupported Windows version?

Comment: Besides, the command prompt isn't part of Visual Studio. It's a standard command prompt that sets the console environment (path, environment variables) to allow the use of MSBuild and VS tools. It doesn't affect network communications

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , Yes. I can open wsdl file in the google chrome. I am using windows 10. Is there a way to set tls 1.2 through the command prompt?

Comment: Again, this has nothing to do with the command prompt, it's controlled by the OS itself. The error you got doesn't mean that TLS1.2 isn't working. It means that client and server couldn't agree how to connect. Perhaps they couldn't agree on the algorithms, perhaps one doesn't trust the other's certificate. Perhaps you used an *old* tool that doesn't understand TLS1.2 - why are you using `wsdl.exe` instead of `svcutil.exe` ? WCF came out in 2008 and the older `wsdl.exe` is in maintenance mode since. I wouldn't be surprised if it only gets version changes with each new SDK release

Comment: Have you tried using `svcutil.exe` instead of `wsdl.exe`? Or install a fresh version of .NET Framework? 4.6.1 is 6 years old and [reaches the end of support in less than 1 year](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-framework-4-5-2-4-6-4-6-1-will-reach-end-of-support-on-april-26-2022/). It's quite possible that nobody noticed that the ancient `wsdl.exe` didn't work with TLS 1.2 and any fixes came *after* TLS1.2 became the default in .NET Framework. `wsdl.exe` is 15 years old and never supported the WS-* interoperability standards. There's no real reason to use it

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that even in the .NET 4.8 SDK, `svcutil.exe` still targets .NET Framework 4.5. This causes the .NET Framework to prevent the application from using TLS 1.2, in the name of backwards compatibility (!?).

The work around, from [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#systemdefaulttlsversions), is to use `regedit.exe` to override the .NET Framework's behavior to always use the latest versions of TLS available on the system. You do this by navigating to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319` key and creating a `DWORD` with named `SystemDefaultTlsVersions` with the value `1` . Or use `notepad.exe` to create a `.reg` file with the following contents and double click on it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
"SystemDefaultTlsVersions"=dword:00000001
```

Note that this will effect all 32-bit application on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can just try http:// instead of https
i hope this will help